# Primefaces dynamic overlayPanel showing only once

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form with a button that opens a Primafaces `overlayPanel`. 
In the panel there is another button that performs an Ajax action and then closes the overlay.
Here is a simplified version with no Ajax action at all:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="button1" value="Open overlay" type="button"/>
    <p:overlayPanel for="button1" widgetVar="ovl" dynamic="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="ovl.hide();"
                         update="@form"/>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```

Please note that the panel must have `dynamic="true"` because dynamic content must be fetched in the real application, and `update="@form"` is needed in order to update other form components.

The problem is: if I have both attibutes, `dynamic="true"` and `update="@form"` the overlay shows up only the first time. After clicking the "close" button, if I try to click on "open overlay" once more, the panel won't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

(Using PrimeFaces 3.5 and GlassFish 3.1.2.2)

Answer (score 13):

Use `onclick="widgetVar.loadContents()"` in the button dropping down the `overlaypanel`, where `widgetVar` is the var of the `overlayPanel`.

Comment: Thanks It worked. How did you find this method, its not listed in Primefaces User Guide.

Comment: Updated: onclick="PF('widgetVar').loadContents();"

Answer (score 0):

What i noticed with below code is as soon as you do update on the form containing the Open-Overlay-button, it breaks.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="button1" value="Open overlay" type="button"/>
    <p:commandButton value="break things" update="@form" />
    <p:overlayPanel for="button1" dynamic="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Close" update="@form" />
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```

If it is okay to split the form into two, the button embedded in the OverlayPanel, could try to invoke click on the button used to toggle the overlay. Perhaps something in line with below.

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="button1" value="Open overlay" type="button"/>
    <p:overlayPanel for="button1" dynamic="true" >
        <p:commandButton value="Close" update=":formToBeUpdated" onclick="document.getElementById('button1').click();"/>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>

<h:form id="formToBeUpdated">
    <h:inputText value="bleh"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you Aksel. Unfortunately the overlay is part of a composite component used in many different views, so it must be hosted by the parent form element: it cannot define its own form because I'd end up with nested forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your overlayPanel an id and oncompelete of your button show it.
The code goes like this:

```
<h:form>
   <p:commandButton id="button1" value="Open overlay" type="button" oncomplete="PF('ovlID').show()"/>
   <p:overlayPanel id="ovlID" for="button1" widgetVar="ovl" dynamic="true">
      <p:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="ovl.hide();"
                     update="@form"/>
   </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```