# Primefaces Selectors: How to exclude some components when updating the closest form?

Tags: jsf-2, jquery-selectors, primefaces

I'm using a PrimeFaces `commandButton` to issue an Ajax request.
I should set the `update` attribute so that the whole parent form be updated EXCEPT for some specific components (Let's say I've tagged them with `styleClass="noupdate"`).
I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5, so I think PrimeFaces JQuery Selectors may help.
I tried something like this:

```
<!-- ...some inputs/labels to be updated here... -->
<p:overlayPanel styleClass="noupdate">
    <!-- ...some inputs/labels to be updated here... -->
    <p:commandButton id="btnDoIt" value="Do it" 
            update="@(this.closest('form') :not(.noupdate))"/>  
</p:overlayPanel>
```

but it doesn't work (I get a JavaScript Syntax Error).
Is there a way to get what I need?
Notice that:
1) The form id is not known because the button is part of a composite component that can be hosted by any form in different views
2) In my example the `<p:overlayPanel>` itself must not be updated, but any descendant component do.
3) There are more than one form in the view, and I should work on the "current" one only.

Thank you in advance to anyone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as `this` in [PrimeFaces selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf). There are definitely no jQuery functions like `$.closest()` available in PrimeFaces selectors. It has just to be a pure [jQuery-compatible CSS selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), not some JavaScript code.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="@(form :not(.noupdate))"/>
```

#### See also:

- [How to exclude child component in ajax update of a parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614882/how-to-exclude-child-component-in-ajax-update-of-a-parent-component/)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, can we definitely say that there is no way to limit the context of PFS to the "current" form?

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I now see the point of your question; you've multiple forms and this will of course not work as intented at all. I did some quick experiments with `form:eq(1)` and `[id='#{form.clientId}']` but that didn't seem to work at all. I will look closer at PrimeFaces source if the time allows it. In the meanwhile, please unaccept this answer as it didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I ran into this issue to find a workaround for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656856/primefaces-dynamic-overlaypanel-showing-only-once) other problem - don't know if you had time for that too. Anyway, thank you so much, I Always learn a lot of things.