# How to prevent scrollbar re-positioning on update=@form?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a long form, and the client have to scroll vertically the screen to see all fields.

But, every time one of those components with the property `update=@form` is fired, the screen get back to the top position.

So, the question is:

- **There is a way to keep the scroll bar in the same position after an `update=@form` ?**

**Important**: The scroll bar back to the top only in the first `update=@form`, after that, the screen keeps the current position.

I am not sure if it's a bug or I am doing something wrong that is causing that behavior.

And yes, i really have to update the whole form

e.g.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnVerifyLogin" update="@form" value="Verify" 
    actionListener="#{demandController.VerifyLogin()} />
```

Comment: This [post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6924) may help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before, where I had to update the whole form.

What I have learned that when I update the form containing the button that has been pressed (like your Verify button), the browser somehow loses the focus on that button and just scroll back to the top.

I came up with a workaround.

```
<p:commandButton id="btnVerifyLogin" 
                 update="@(form :not(#formId\\:btnVerifyLogin))" 
                 value="Verify" 
                 actionListener="#{demandController.VerifyLogin()} />
```

Basically I update the form but not the button, this way the browser keeps the scroll as it is.

Others would suggest that `onstart` we can call `var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();` in order to preserve our scroll position, and `oncomplete` we call `$("html").scrollTop(scroll);`, but this won't work since the `oncomplete` won't be triggered since the button is updated inside the form!

Again this will work only with Primefaces 4, and recently I avoid updating full forms, I prefer to use selectors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Hatem! Your reply didn't worked as expected, but it led me to the solution. What i had to do was exclude the update of the parent document, which was "stealing" the focus. This question also helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790160/primefaces-selectors-how-to-exclude-some-components-when-updating-the-closest-f

Comment: Maybe my testing page hierarchy is competently different.. that's why my trick worked :) @Pellizon